# How do I only get workday data from pandas datareader?

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, pandas-datareader

I am trying to get only workday data when importing Bitcoin quotes from yahoo finance. However, when I try to import it, it also gives weekend data, which I do not need. I transfered all data to .csv files to check what the problem was, and found that the bitcoin data included weekends and holidays. Since bitcoin is traded 24/7, I am getting more data. How do I get only data from workdays? 
Code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2017,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2017,2,1)
a = web.DataReader('BTC-USD', 'yahoo', start, end)
a.to_csv('BTC.csv')
```

(Coded in Spyder, Python 3.7)

Comment: I believe the answer has been given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803040/remove-non-business-days-rows-from-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web

a = web.DataReader('BTC-USD', 'yahoo', '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01')
a_business_days = a[a.index.dayofweek < 5]
```