# How to omit only weekends from my data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I am working on a project to create an algorithmic trader. However, I want to remove the weekends from my data frame as it ruins the data as shown in [image: this image.] I have tried to do somethings I found on StackOverflow but I get an error that the type is Timestamp and so I can't use that technique. It also isn't a column in the data frame. I'm new to python so I'm not very sure but I think it's an index since when I go through the .index function it shows me the date and time. I'm sorry if these are stupid questions but I am new to python and pandas.

**Here is my code:**

```
#import all the libraries
import nsetools as ns
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import yfinance as yf

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
a = input("Enter the ticker name you wish to apply strategy to")
ticker = yf.Ticker(a)
hist = ticker.history(period="1mo", interval="15m")
print(hist)

plt.figure(figsize=(12.5, 4.5))
plt.plot(hist['Close'], label=a)
plt.title('close price history')
plt.xlabel("13 Nov 2020 too 13 Dec 2020")
plt.ylabel("Close price")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

EDIT: On the suggestion of a user, I tried to modify my code to this

```
refinedlist = hist[hist.index.dayofweek<5]plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
a = input("Enter the ticker name you wish to apply strategy to")
ticker = yf.Ticker(a)
hist = ticker.history(period="1mo", interval="15m")
refinedlist = hist[hist.index.dayofweek<5]
print (refinedlist)
```

And graphed that, but the graph still includes the weekends on the x axis.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove non-business days rows from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803040/remove-non-business-days-rows-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I did exactly what that says, added "refinedlist = hist[hist.index.dayofweek<5]" and plotted that, but yet it plots the weekends, with the graph looking exactly how it did in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, stock market data does not exist because the market is closed on holidays and national holidays. The reason for this is that your unit of acquisition is time, so there is also no data from the time the market closes to the time it opens the next day.

For example, I graphed the first 50 results. (The x-axis doesn't seem to be correct.)

```
plt.plot(hist['Close'][:50], label=a)
```

[image]

As one example, if you include holidays and national holidays and draw a graph with missing values for the times when the market is not open, you get the following.

```
new_idx = pd.date_range(hist.index[0], hist.index[-1], freq='15min')
hist = hist.reindex(new_idx, fill_value=np.nan)
```

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import yfinance as yf

# plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
# a = input("Enter the ticker name you wish to apply strategy to")
a = 'AAPL'
ticker = yf.Ticker(a)
hist = ticker.history(period="1mo", interval="15m")
new_idx = pd.date_range(hist.index[0], hist.index[-1], freq='15min')
hist = hist.reindex(new_idx, fill_value=np.nan)

plt.figure(figsize=(12.5, 4.5))
plt.plot(hist['Close'], label=a)
plt.title('close price history')
plt.xlabel("13 Nov 2020 too 13 Dec 2020")
plt.ylabel("Close price")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What you are saying makes a lot of sense, does that mean the data is supposed to be like that? Because the chart certainly shouldn't have those gaps